# How to get value onCahnge event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, calendar

I am using [react-input-calendar](https://github.com/Rudeg/react-input-calendar). I want to get the value of the date onChange event and then pass it to new page.
How can I do that?

Code is as below:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: new Date(),inputdate:''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(newDate, event) { 
    console.log(newDate);
    this.setState({inputdate:newDate});
}

<Calendar format='dddd DD MMM' closeOnSelect={true} date={this.state.value}
ref="inputdate" inputName="inputdate" computableFormat='MM-DD-YYYY' onChange=
{this.handleChange.bind(this,"inputdate")} />
```

How can I get value in `handleChange`?

Comment: What do you mean the setState isn't working? Are you actually using it somewhere? If you get rid of "inputdate" on the end of the `bind` it should come through when you change dates.

`this.setState({inputdate:newDate}, function() { console.log(this.state.inputdate) });`

If this has the correct value then you can just do `<div>{this.state.inputdate}</div>` in render.

Delete `inputdate:''` from the constructor too. It's not needed. You need to debug this code youself and step through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> props.onChange,
> Function
>
> default: null
>
> Set a function that will be triggered whenever there is a change in the selected date. It will return the date in the props.computableFormat format.

According to the docs it should be available like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
handleChange(newDate, event) {
    //newDate should be passed here
    console.log(newDate);
}

<Calendar format='dddd DD MMM' closeOnSelect={true} date={this.state.value0}
ref="inputdate" inputName="inputdate" computableFormat='MM-DD-YYYY' onChange=
{this.handleChange} />
```

Check the [src](https://github.com/Rudeg/react-input-calendar/blob/master/src/index.js) code of the library and also the properties on the object passed in. It looks like the library calls the onChange prop and passes in `newDate`.

```
if (this.props.onChange) {
    this.props.onChange(computableDate)
}
```

Comment: Its throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani try now

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani No. You don't need that. that's the src code from the library. It's calling the `onChange` func that we pass in with the newdate. Just look at the `handleChange` code I edited

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani bind it in the constructor as it won't create a new function each time unlike if you did it like before. see edit